# spring mvc I do not see the error message in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

This is the form object:
Here I put the java annotations to validate the form object so that the name field has a length of at least 1.
Here's a small code snippet:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;   

public class Persona {
       @NotNull
       @Size(min=1)
       private String nome;
       private String cognome;
       private String dataNascita;
       private String sesso;
       private String cittaNascita;
       private String cittaResidenza;
       private String nazione;
       private String codiceFiscale;
       private String indirizzo;
       private String telefonoCellulare;
       private String telefonoFisso;
        private String email;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {import javax.validation.constraints.Size;



public class Persona {
       @NotNull
       @Size(min=1)
       private String nome;
       private String cognome;
       private String dataNascita;
       private String sesso;
       private String cittaNascita;
       private String cittaResidenza;
       private String nazione;
       private String codiceFiscale;
       private String indirizzo;
       private String telefonoCellulare;
       private String telefonoFisso;
        private String email;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
        this.nome = nome;
    }
```

persona.jsp the form :

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Informazioni Persona</h2>
<form:form method="POST" action="/Esercizio1SpringMVC/addPersona">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <form:errors path="*" />
        <td><form:label path="nome">Nome</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="nome" /></td>
        <form:errors path="nome"  />
    </tr>
```

The check arrives in risultato.jsp, but the controller result.hasErrors () returns false even when I enter any text for the name of the form field

```
package com.springMVC;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;




@Controller
public class PersonaController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView persona() {
      return new ModelAndView("persona", "command", new Persona());
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/addPersona", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addPersona( @ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") @Valid Persona persona, BindingResult result, 
   ModelMap model) {

       if(result.hasErrors()) {
           System.out.println("bbb");
           model.addAttribute("Persona", persona);
           return "person";
       } 
        System.out.println("ccc");
      model.addAttribute("nome", persona.getNome());
      model.addAttribute("cognome", persona.getCognome());
      model.addAttribute("dataNascita", persona.getDataNascita());
      model.addAttribute("sesso", persona.getSesso());
      model.addAttribute("cittaNascita", persona.getCittaNascita());
      model.addAttribute("cittaResidenza", persona.getCittaResidenza());
      model.addAttribute("nazione", persona.getNazione());
      model.addAttribute("codiceFiscale", persona.getCodiceFiscale());
      model.addAttribute("indirizzo", persona.getIndirizzo());
      model.addAttribute("telefonoCellulare", persona.getTelefonoCellulare());
      model.addAttribute("telefonoFisso", persona.getTelefonoFisso());
      model.addAttribute("email", persona.getEmail());

      return "risultato";
   }
}



<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Informazioni Persona</h2>
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>${nome}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cognome</td>
        <td>${cognome}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data di nascita</td>
        <td>${dataNascita}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sesso</td>
        <td>${sesso}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Citta di nascita</td>
        <td>${cittaNascita}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Citta di residenza</td>
        <td>${cittaResidenza}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nazione</td>
        <td>${nazione}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Codice fiscale</td>
        <td>${codiceFiscale}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Indirizzo</td>
        <td>${indirizzo}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Telefono cellulare</td>
        <td>${telefonoCellulare}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Telefono fisso</td>
        <td>${telefonoFisso}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>${email}</td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Adrian Thompson Phillips

Comment: you mean I posted the jsp but I have not solved the problem @Mufanu

Comment: yes i posted the jsp but i have not solved the problem

Comment: If I correctly understand, you leave the field `nome` empty in the form, your controller method is called, and `result.hasErrors()` is still false ? If all that is true, do you have a validator (like `HibernateValidator`) in your project ?

Comment: Yes. I have included in the project hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar and javax.validatio-1.0.0.GA.jar. But do not use any Java class as a validator, use the controller and the annotation in the bean which I have posted the code

Answer (score 0):

You should use @RequestParam in your controller example;

@RequestMapping(value = "/addPersona", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addPersona(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
            Locale locale, Model model,

```
          @RequestParam( value = "name", required = false ) String name
```

) {

//use name in here

}